# SwiftUI Search bar - Please help my simplify my code

Tags: swiftui, searchable

again maybe a beginner question.
I've implemented a search function in my app. But I'm very unhappy with my code. I know I have to have to put my searchText into the .searchable() {...}
But also with help from different tutorials my knowledge isn't good enough to do this.
Could you please habe a look into my code and give me a hint so I could learn from your solution?

````
//
//  FavoriteView.swift
//  Blindzeln_Prototyp
//
//  Created by Michael Ecke on 25.01.22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct FavoriteView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var blindzeln: BLINDzeln
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List{
                ForEach(blindzeln.favorites, id: \.entryID) { item in
                    
                    if searchText==""{
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: FavoriteDetailView(item: item)) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20.0) {
                            Text(item.title)
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            Text(item.textBody)
                                .font(.body)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .lineLimit(2)
                            BigDivider()
                        }
                    }.listRowSeparatorTint(.primary)
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
                else {
                    if item.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) || item.textBody.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText){
                        NavigationLink(destination: FavoriteDetailView(item: item)) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20.0) {
                                Text(item.title)
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                Text(item.textBody)
                                    .font(.body)
                                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                    .lineLimit(2)
                                BigDivider()
                            }
                        }.listRowSeparatorTint(.primary)
                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    }
                }
                
                }
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
                .onMove(perform: onMove)
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText) {}
            ```
````

Comment: You need to post the entire view struct, not just this portion.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. If you issue is just making your code "better" SO is not the place.

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.You haven't even described your problem. if your issue is searchable I suggest you start with the [Apple videos](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10018) the one licked has it at around minute 15:20

Comment: Hi Yrb, ok. I could post the rest. But I think I have to solve my problem in this part of the code or am I wrong? Updated: Code copied into question

Comment: Hi lorem ipsum. If you can see, I use the NavigationLink two times. One if the search string is empty and the second comparing the search text with the strings item.title and textbody. It should be possible to put this into the .searchable(). But with reading tutorials I don't know how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the rest of the code to test, I can't be sure, but you should be able to condense your code like so:

```
struct FavoriteView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var blindzeln: BLINDzeln
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List{
                ForEach(blindzeln.favorites.filter { searchText.isEmpty ||($0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) || $0.textBody.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)) }, id: \.entryID){ item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: FavoriteDetailView(item: item)) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20.0) {
                            Text(item.title)
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            Text(item.textBody)
                                .font(.body)
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .lineLimit(2)
                            BigDivider()
                        }
                    }.listRowSeparatorTint(.primary)
                        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
            .onMove(perform: onMove)
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText) {}
        // Nothing changed past here...
    }
}
```

Essentially the filter I set up is this:

1. if `searchText` is empty, return TRUE so the item is used;
2. if `searchText` is not empty, evaluate the other side of the OR which is 2 conditions with an OR. If either `title` OR `textBody` contains `searchText`, return TRUE so item is used;
3. if everything returns false, don't use item.

One last thing, rename your `entryID` in your model struct to `id`, make the model struct conform to `Identifiable` and then your `ForEach` (leaving out the `.filter` can be this:

```
ForEach(blindzeln.favorites) { item in
```

as an `Identifiable` struct does not need to use `id:` in a `ForEach` initializer.

Comment: It works. Thanks to your explanation. this is what I want to do. but I thought I have to put it into the searchable... If I remove the id, Xcode prompt me a JSON failure. But this I have to read an understand the next time. Maybe this looks like a simple problem for you, but with your code example I made a step further in understanding swift :-)

Comment: In your `Codable` struct change the coding key that says something like `case entryID = "entryID"` to `case id = "entryID"`. See if that fixes the JSON error.